# How to convert amount to alphabets in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose i want to convert the amount 156 to one hundred and fifty six in oracle sql how could i do so
and also suppose there are many numbers create a function also so it takes the number and convert it automatically. I have to use this code in oracle SQL

'Suppose i want to convert the amount 156 to one hundred and fifty six in oracle sql how could i do so
and also suppose there are many numbers create a function also so it takes the number and convert it automatically. I have to use this code in oracle SQL'

Answer (score 2):

A simple option is to use `to_char` function with Julian date parameter:

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date(156, 'J'), 'JSP') result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------
ONE HUNDRED FIFTY-SIX

SQL>
```

---

If you need a more complex (but better) option, have a look at [spell_number](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650) function on AskTom.